# Javascript : Post URL 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript

am facing error in ai.0.js file which I dnt have any idea.  This error get thrown while calling the ajax function and setting headers :

```
beforeSend: function (d, c) {
            d.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + IportalauthContext.GetOauthToken(iPortal.global.common.DefaultResource))
        },
```

[image]

Please do provide any suggestion

Comment: 500 status is from the server. Have a look in the network tab instead. You likely format your request incorrectly

Comment: more information is needed... error 500 could mean multiple things depending of the service that you are trying to use

Comment: The status 500 is returned from the server. You haven't provided enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The details will likely be in the server's log.